# Une question d'ellipse de la préposition « de » devant le complément de nom dans les compléments coordonnés

Tags: prépositions, coordination, de, ellipse, complément-de-nom

1/ Une construction telle que « *suppression d'un ou de plusieurs postes* », dans laquelle se trouve une ellipse du nom complément, est normale (tout au moins je le pense) mais on est tenté de la raccourcir, c'est à dire de supprimer la seconde occurrence de la préposition « de » et donc d'écrire « *suppression d'un ou  plusieurs postes* » ; est-ce que cette possibilité est admise ?
 
2/ Assez bizarrement, si l'ellipse qui vient d'être mentionnée ne semble pas tout à fait naturelle, la suivante me le parait encore moins :  « *suppression d'un poste ou  plusieurs* » ; que peut-on dire de ce cas-ci ?
3/ Est-ce que la  variante de cette construction  dans laquelle parait un adverbe entraine un changement, par exemple dans « *suppression d'un ou (de) possiblement plusieurs postes* » ?
4/ Qu'en est-il de la construction similaire dans laquelle il n'y a pas d'ellipse de nom comme par exemple dans la construction « *suppression d'un poste ou de plusieurs sections* » ? Peut-on écrire « *suppression d'un poste ou  plusieurs sections* » ?
5/ La prescription pour « 4/ » reste-t-elle valide lorsque « ou » est remplacé par « et » ?

Comment: Effectivement, je pense que ma réponse reste correcte car elle traite des deux, ellipse et élision, mais ma remarque ne fait pas de sens, je la supprime :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon moi, et je n'ai malheureusement pas de référence à fournir, tous les exemples que vous avez donnés sont parfaitement corrects. Pour répondre point par point, malheureusement basée uniquement sur mon ressenti (vous l'aurez compris je ne suis pas le plus fin technicien de la langue française) :

1/ Le "un" de votre exemple n'est pas indéfini, l’élision est donc une possibilité mais pas une obligation. Écrire "Suppression de un ou (de) plusieurs postes" est donc correct, et l’élision est surtout utile à l'oral car plus facile à prononcer. Partant de là, supprimer le second "de" est de fait plus naturel car il s'agit d'une vraie répétition, donc "Suppression de un ou plusieurs postes" est correct, et je ne vois donc pas pourquoi l’élision rendrait la phrase "Suppression d'un ou plusieurs postes" fausse. Donc "est-ce que cette possibilité est admise ?", je dirais oui

2/ Le manque de "naturel" de votre phrase (que je ressens également) est je pense lié à l'ordre des mots plus qu'à une quelconque élision, le terme "plusieurs" étant je pense toujours placé devant le nom qu'il désigne quand celui-ci fait partie de la phrase. Supprimer le "de" en plus de la suppression du "poste" rend donc je pense la phrase peu élégante. On évitera donc sans doute cette formulation mais l'utiliser ne représente pas, je pense , un  erreur grammaticale.

3/ Toujours selon moi il n'y as pas de changement induit par ce nouvel adverbe.

4/ Le "de" étant là pour suivre le "Supression", selon moi peu importe le nom qui suit, supprimer le second "de" et élider le premier en "d'" reste correct (à supposer que mes réponses précédentes le soient elles aussi)

5/ En restant cohérent avec ma logique, je ne vois pas pourquoi la formule serait moins correcte avec "et"

Comment: Je veux bien vous croire n'étant moi-même en aucun cas un professionnel de la langue mais en l'absence de rėférence dans chacune de nos réponses je préfèrerais attendre avant de la supprimer le cas échéant. Ces formulations ne me paraissent pas erronées mais peut-être un abus de langage très répandu m'induit-il en erreur.

Answer (score 1):

On dira « suppression d'un ou plusieurs postes », car les mots coordonnées ont la même nature et la même fonction, car la lecture se fait de la gauche vers la droite, car un déterminant n'est pas utilisable sans son nom.

*Même si l'on aurait pu dire* « suppression d'**un** ou de plusieurs postes » ou « suppression d'un poste ou de **plusieurs** », ces expressions ne sont pas consistantes au niveau grammatical ([voir aussi la réponse de jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36223/19460)). Le nom est un constituant fondamental du groupe nominal.

Le procédé qui consiste à ajouter des éléments dans une phrase est *l'expansion*. On procède à l'expansion du groupe nominal « un poste » via la coordination.

Les autres propositions sont infondées. En outre, on dit sûrement « une ou plusieurs suppressions de postes ». On pourrait éventuellement dire « une suppression de postes » ou « des suppressions de postes », car le complément du nom ne s'accorde pas en genre et en nombre avec le nom-noyau.

Comment: L'analyse devient compliquée dans certains cas. Comme avec le nom sous-jacent où on pourrait trouver le déterminant devant l'adjectif uniquement. Ensuite devant un syntagme prépositionnel, une relative, ou une prop. débutant par _comme_, on pourrait trouver seul un déterminant qui sert aussi de pronom, dont les numéraux cardinaux et _plusieurs_ ( « Une boîte en fer et deux en bois »). Ensuite t'as d'autres possibilités avec certains déterminants comme _des_ mais ça relève de la langue populaire ou enfantine ( « Des cartes postales en couleur et des en noir »). Voir LBU14§571,269,218,576 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux formes *d'un ou de plusieurs* et *d'un ou plusieurs* sont courantes, la deuxième étant en progression. On retrouve les deux dans une même phrase de Diderot (Encyclopédie, 1778):

[image]

La forme *de un ou de plusieurs* est utilisée en français parlé, mais se retrouve rarement à l'écrit.

La forme *d'un poste ou plusieurs sections* me semble incorrecte quel que soit le niveau de langue.

La forme *d'un poste et plusieurs sections* parait peu idiomatique.

[image]